# How can I track which program is deleting my files?

Tags: filesystems

I'm having an intermittent problem that I'm trying to track down. Every now and then a significant portion of my `src` directory is being erased (like 90%+ of all files). I'll be working on my project and all of a sudden I'll get an error, look at `git status` and it will show nearly all of the files in my repo have been deleted. Then I have to run a bunch of `git checkout --` commands and I'm lucky if I don't lose a bunch of work.

Can I use `inotify` or another program to watch my `src` directory and report which program is deleting the files? I have a feeling it's gulp but I have no evidence beyond the anecdotal, and I don't want to bother a specific project until I've nailed down the source of the problem.

OS X, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use lsof to monitor your directory and capture your output to a file (or have a terminal up.)
I tested `lsof +D ~/Downloads/ -r 2` out on my OS X, and it seems to work fine.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157064/monitoring-files-continuously-with-lsof

Answer (score 0):

[Auditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/audit.8.html).  This is one thing that auditing is **designed** for.

Don't roll your own.  Don't use tools designed for other purposes.  Use the auditing facilities your operating system provides.

[Basic tutorial for OS X is here:](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/openbsm-auditing-on-mac-os-x/)

> **OpenBSM auditing on Mac OS X**
>
> Way back in 10.3.x, Apple submitted Mac OS X and Mac OS X Server to
>   the National Information Assurance Partnership for Common Criteria
>   certification. Common Criteria certification means that the the
>   covered hardware and software has been tested and evaluated to make
>   sure that it meets an established set of requirements for security and
>   data protection. 10.3.6 and 10.3.6 Server were tested and were found
>   to meet Evaluation Assurance Level 3 (EAL3) for Common Criteria
>   certification.
>
> As part of that certification effort, a new piece of software appeared
>   from Apple: the Common Criteria Tools audit software. This software
>   was OpenBSM, which is an open source implementation of Sun’s Basic
>   Security Module (BSM) security audit API and file format. ...

Yes, it's a pain to do properly.  But it **will** work, and the results will be definitive.