# How to monitor file open and file read events in OSX

Tags: macos, dtrace, fsevents

I have researched on [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4) and [Kernel Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH5-SW2) to identify how to monitor events. Unfortunately, these allow notifications only upon modifications, renames or delete events (events that update the state). I need to get a callback upon file open or file read events (for the current user). I understand that the events for files that do not have appropriate permissions will not be accessible.

Any pointers will be helpful.

NOTE: DTrace is out of question as System Integrity Protection disables DTrace and I do not have the option of disabling System Integrity Protection

Comment: I suppose you could do this if you control the filesystem (e.g. a FUSE filesystem). But otherwise it sounds like it might be an impossible task to watch these events without dtrace/strace.

Comment: @jtbandes Sadly, I wouldn't be surprised if whoever is mandating DTrace remain disabled for security reason would approve such control of the file system.  "No, the rules say you can't have matches or lighters because they're dangerous.  But we approved your request for a flamethrower.  We've also thrown in a [deep-fryer and a frozen turkey](http://www.oregonlive.com/cooking/2014/11/12_all-time_deep-fried_turkey.html)."

Comment: Also, see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35164352/4756299

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Thanks for the link. In my case, I am not trying to do auditing. I am developing software that needs to get these events in near real time. Also, /var/audit access is limited to super user... may not have access during regular run.. Just at install time. I am exploring another avenue right now. If I get something working, I will post the answer.

Comment: @ChetanNadgouda  Good luck.  You have a tough task.  You can do it either at the user level by interposing a library, but that's fragile, bug-prone, and will break things in unexpected ways.  [Tivoli SANergy](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246146.pdf) used that method - and it was a nightmare in many ways.  Or you can do it in the kernel, which, given you're not allowed to use DTrace, would be allowing you to have a flamethrower when you're not allowed to have a lighter:  "You can't use DTrace because of security concerns, but you can insert custom unvetted code into the kernel."

Comment: To complete the loop, I ended up using Kernel Extension. For those who are interested in knowing how to do this, Take a look at [KAutoORama](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/KauthORama/Listings/Read_Me_About_KauthORama_txt.html)

Answer (score 1):

**In macOS >=10.11**

In macOS >= 11, you can use a `Endpoint Security` `System Extension`. See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity) and the "AUTH" version of the "Monitoring System Events with Endpoint Security" [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/monitoring_system_events_with_endpoint_security).

---

**In macOS 10.4-10.10**

In macOS 10.4-10.10 use a `Kernel Extension` using `Kernel Authorization`. See [archived Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2127/_index.html) and this [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/KauthORama/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003633-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).